# Creating Dict<enum, List<objec>> from List<object> using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have the following enums and class:

```
public enum SymbolTypeEnum
{
    [Description("Forex")]
    forex = 0,
    [Description("Metals")]
    metals = 1,
    [Description("Commodities")]
    commodities = 2,
    [Description("Indices")]
    indices = 3,
    [Description("Cryptocurrency")]
    cryptocurrency = 4,
    [Description("Other")]
    other = 5
}

public enum SymbolClassificationEnum
{
    [Description("None")]
    none = 0,
    [Description("Major")]
    major = 1,
    [Description("Minor")]
    minor = 2,
    [Description("Exotic")]
    exotic = 3
}
public class SymbolSettingsModel
{
    [PrimaryKeyAttribute, Unique]
    public string symbolName { get; set; }
    public SymbolTypeEnum symbolType { get; set; }
    public SymbolClassificationEnum symbolClassification { get; set; }
}
```

I have a `List<SymbolSettingsModel> symbolSettings;`

My goal is to generate a `Dictionary<SymbolTypeEnum, List<SymbolDescr>> typeSymbolsSettingsData;`

Where SymbolDescr is:

```
class SymbolDescr
{
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public int classification { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is to group them by symbolType and use it as a Key for the dictionary, and generate a list of SymbolDescr. Here is my code so far:

```
typeSymbolsSettingsData = symbolSettings.GroupBy(p => p.symbolType)
            .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.ToList());
```

I am stuck at this point, do you have any ideas how I can do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Select` to project your `SymbolSettingsModel` instances into `SymbolDescr` instances:

```
typeSymbolsSettingsData = symbolSettings
    .GroupBy(p => p.symbolType)
    .ToDictionary(
        p => p.Key,
        p => p.Select(x => new SymbolDescr
        {
            symbol = x.symbolName,
            classification = (int)x.symbolClassification
        })
        .ToList());
```

You should also try to comply with the [.Net property naming convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members#names-of-properties) which mandates the use of PascalCase.